# Inversion of multivariate function

Tags: functions, inverse

Consider the function $$(x,y)\in \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}\mapsto f(x,y)\in \mathcal{F}$$

Question: Which characteristics should have $f$ such that we can uniquely define from $f$ the "inverse" function
$$(f,y)\in \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{Y}\mapsto x(f,y)\in \mathcal{X}$$

I think that $f$ has to be bijective in $x$. Is this sufficient, or do we need something else?

Comment: Hmm I mean, if you think of the input pair $(x,y)$ as a single element $u$, then it suffices that the map is injective and surjective in $u$. 

Said another way, just check if for every output in has only one pair $(x,y)$ corresponding to it (injectivity) and if every output pair in the target has a corresponding input (surjectivity).

Comment: Are you saying that it has to be bijective in both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No, I am saying think of $(x,y)$ as a single thing. Then, you can directly say that it is invertible if for each element in output, there is only one $(x,y)$ input and every $(x,y) $  in output has at least a single $(x,y)$ in input.

I am not sure if bijectivity in x and y individually suggests, bijectivity in (x,y)